# How do I combine input type date and input type time in one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time

I have an angularjs UI which asks the user to input a date and a time. Now I want to **combine the two in one date type** so that I can send it to REST API. How do I do it?

My html code is

```
<div class="col-md-7">
     <input type="date" id="exampleInput" ng-model="UIcontroller.JobDataModel.date"
      placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required/>

<div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="time" id="exampleInput1" ng-model="UIcontroller.JobDataModel.time"
     placeholder="hh:mm:ss:" required/>
```

How do I do it in the controller ? Should I just concatenate the two ng- models?

Comment: We cannot tell you how if we do not know the format expected by the REST backend. However, a `Date` in JavaScript is the combination of date and time. You can definitely create a `Date` object to hold both values.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine date & time input by following way-

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="dateTime" id="exampleInput3" ng-model="UIcontroller.JobDataModel.datetime">
```

Hope this will hep you.

Answer (score 0):

no need to add to input field, you can use one input field for both date and time, here is the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/DxQWu6HrRfwtQ8wsOP2A?p=preview)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>User Input</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading... </my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

you need to import app/boot

Answer (score 0):

You can combine date and time, by creating a date-time string by joining both of them first and then, parsing it into a date.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.UIcontroller = {
      JobDataModel: {
        date: new Date(),
        time: new Date()
      }
    };
    $scope.result = '';

    $scope.updateResult = function() {
      var myDate = $scope.UIcontroller.JobDataModel.date,
        myTime = $scope.UIcontroller.JobDataModel.time,
        combinedDateString = (myDate.toDateString() + " " + myTime.toTimeString()),
        combinedDate = new Date(combinedDateString);

      $scope.result = combinedDate;
    }

    $scope.updateResult();
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="myDate" ng-model="UIcontroller.JobDataModel.date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" ng-change='updateResult()' required/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="myTime" ng-model="UIcontroller.JobDataModel.time" placeholder="hh:mm:ss:" ng-change='updateResult()' required/>

      <div>Result: [{{result.toString()}}]</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... for your input field add `"ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"`
example:

```
<input type="date" id="exampleInput" ng-model="UIcontroller.JobDataModel.date"
      placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" required/>
```

once you have getterSetter set to true you can access the value entered by user in your controller...

```
  var _date = new Date();
  var _time = new Date();
  $scope.UIcontroller = {};
  $scope.UIcontroller.JobDataModel = {
    date: function(newDate) {
      return arguments.length ? (_date = newDate) : _date;

    },
    time: function(newTime) {
      return arguments.length ? (_time = newTime) : _time;

    },
    finalDate: function() {
      return (_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + _date.getDate() + '/' + _date.getFullYear() + ' ' + _time.getHours() + ':' + _time.getMinutes();
    }

  };
```

You can see my rough solution here: https://plnkr.co/edit/BjXL114HLl2qMqy0wpOR?p=preview

Good luck!